# How to get the definition of customized analyzer in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an analyzer called test_analyzer, right now I wanna see the definition of it, but I used `/myindex/_mapping` api which was not able to show the definition. How can I get it out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `localhost:9200/your_index_name` you should see `your_index_name -> settings -> index -> analysis -> analyzer` and there are your analyzers.  I just made one called `lowercase`.

For example:

[image]